# How to show only those records (from record 1) in an Adapter which are set as 'true' (in record 2) in Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch and populate my Adapter with only those records which are set as true (in a record), and if they are false, I would not like to fetch and populate my Adapter with them.
I am basically trying to build a Train Pantry Food Ordering System in which Passengers can order food from Pantry car. But **with one condition** :

*Food should be available in the particular train's Pantry car in which the Passenger is travelling.*

Here is my Realtime Database :

[image: Catalogues Database]

[image: Foodinfo Database]

Here, Firstly I want to fetch the boolean values for entered train number from Catalog -> (trainno) -> data(true/false), then accordingly, if it is true, I want to populate my Adapter with **those food items only** while getting food-item data from foodinfo -> (foodname) -> data.

Here are my codes :

Food :

```
public class Food {
    private String description;
    private String imageurl;
    private String foodname;

    public Food(String description, String imageurl, String foodname) {
        this.description = description;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        this.foodname = foodname;
    }

    public Food(){}

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public String getFoodname() {
        return foodname;
    }

    public void setFoodname(String foodname) {
        this.foodname = foodname;
    }
}
```

FoodAdapter:

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.Viewholder>{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<Food> mFoods;

    public FoodAdapter(Context mContext, List<Food> mFoods) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mFoods = mFoods;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.food_item, parent, false);
        return new FoodAdapter.Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position) {
        Food food = mFoods.get(position);

        holder.foodDescription.setText(food.getDescription());
        Picasso.get().load(food.getImageurl()).into(holder.foodImage);
        holder.foodName.setText(food.getFoodname());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("foodinfo").child(food.getFoodname())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Food food1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

                holder.foodName.setText(food1.getFoodname());
                holder.foodDescription.setText(food1.getDescription());
                Picasso.get().load(food.getImageurl()).into(holder.foodImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFoods.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView foodImage;
        public TextView foodName;
        public TextView foodDescription;

        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            foodImage =itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);
            foodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
            foodDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_description);
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewMenu;
    private FoodAdapter foodAdapter;
    private List<Food> foodList;

    private List<String> availableFoodsList; // foods available for a train passenger only that will be shown.

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerViewMenu = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_foods);
        recyclerViewMenu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerViewMenu.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        foodList = new ArrayList<>();
        foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(getContext(), foodList);
        recyclerViewMenu.setAdapter(foodAdapter);

        availableFoodsList = new ArrayList<>();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should modify the underlayer data (foodList) then use Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the recycler view for any adapter data changes

Comment: I got your point.. thankyou. But, how can I fetch for boolean values from catalogues?

Comment: you should sync the data between foodlist and DB if any side data changed.
Why not use t-sql cmd to get data from DB?